# regular expression for checking attributes in an html tag

Tags: regex

In an HTML source I need to extract any simple text inside a FONT tag with exactly (no more, no less) these 3 attributes, in any order: size=5, color="red", face="verdana".

The regular expression must thus for example extract all the following "randomtext" except the last four.

```
<font size=5 color="red" face="verdana">randomtext</font>
<font size=5 face="verdana" color="red">randomtext</font>
<font color="red" size=5 face="verdana">randomtext</font>
<font color="red" face="verdana" size=5>randomtext</font>
<font face="verdana" size=5 color="red">randomtext</font>
<font face="verdana" color="red" size=5>randomtext</font>
<font size=5 size=5 size=5>randomtext</font>
<font face="verdana" color="red" size=5 foobar="random">randomtext</font>
<font face="verdana" color="red" size=5 foobar="random=pippo">randomtext</font>
<font face="verdana" color="red" size=5 garbagetext>randomtext</font>
```

I solved the "in any order" problem by using 3 look-aheads:

```
<font(?=[^>]* size=5)(?=[^>]* color="red")(?=[^>]* face="verdana")[^>]*>([^<]+)</font>
```

...or for more html flexibility:

```
<\s*font(?=[^>]*\s+size\s*=\s*5)(?=[^>]*\scolor\s*=\s*["']red["'])(?=[^>]*\sface\s*=\s*["']verdana["'])[^>]*>\s*([^<]+?)\s*<\s*/font\s*>
```

The problem is that it also matches the last three.
How can I exclude those matching?
(obviously in a general and reasonable short/efficient way, i.e. without codyfing all possible positive combinations and without using literal negative expressions that work only on my examples)

Comment: What language are you using?  This task is much more easily handled with a proper HTML parsing library.

Comment: Michael, it must be solved in a single regular expression, language independent. Regex flavor is PCRE.

Comment: I already found a short single-regex solution but it repeats one time all the three attributes, doubling the lenght of the regex of my examples.  Although it's not long like if I write all the possible combinations I think that it is still not the shorter/best solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way, also according with who says that regexp is not the tool for the job:

Content of `script.pl` (with the regexp inside and explained):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    printf qq[Text matched: %s\t (original string: %s)\n], $1, $& if 
    m/ 
        # At begin of line, '<' character plus optional space.
        \A < \s*
        # Literal 'font' word.
        font
        # Mandatory space.
        \s+
        # Positive look-ahead for string 'size=5'
        (?= .* size \s* = \s* 5 (?:\s+|>) )   
        # Positive look-ahead for string 'face="verdana"'
        (?= .* face \s* = \s* "verdana" (?:\s+|>) )
        # Positive look-ahead for string 'color="red"'
        (?= .* color \s* = \s* "red" (?:\s+|>) )
        # If last three look-ahead succeed, match them.
        (?:size\s*=\s*5\s*|color\s*=\s*"red"\s*|face\s*=\s*"verdana"\s*){3}
        # Literal '>' character.
        >
        # Text between tags.
        ([^>]+)
        # Close tag and match end of string.
        <\/font> \Z
    /x;
}

__DATA__
<font size=5 color="red" face="verdana">randomtext</font>
<font size=5 face="verdana" color="red">randomtext</font>
<font color="red" size=5 face="verdana">randomtext</font>
<font color="red" face="verdana" size=5>randomtext</font>
<font face="verdana" size=5 color="red">randomtext</font>
<font face="verdana" color="red" size=5>randomtext</font>
<font size=5 size=5 size=5>randomtext</font>
<font face="verdana" color="red" size=5 foobar="random">randomtext</font>
<font face="verdana" color="red" size=5 foobar="random=pippo">randomtext</font>
<font face="verdana" color="red" size=5 garbagetext>randomtext</font>
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

With following result:

```
Text matched: randomtext         (original string: <font size=5 color="red" face="verdana">randomtext</font>)
Text matched: randomtext         (original string: <font size=5 face="verdana" color="red">randomtext</font>)
Text matched: randomtext         (original string: <font color="red" size=5 face="verdana">randomtext</font>)
Text matched: randomtext         (original string: <font color="red" face="verdana" size=5>randomtext</font>)
Text matched: randomtext         (original string: <font face="verdana" size=5 color="red">randomtext</font>)
Text matched: randomtext         (original string: <font face="verdana" color="red" size=5>randomtext</font>)
```

Comment: Great Birei, you arrived to the same solution I arrived to, that has the only "defect" of repeating the 3 attributes one time.

Answer (score 0):

You recognize that this is getting difficult? If you have another possibility, use it!

For regex try this:

```
<font(?=[^>]* size=5)(?=[^>]* color="red")(?=[^>]* face="verdana")(?![^>]*(?<!color|size|face)=)(?:\s+[^>\s=]+=[^>\s=]+\s*)+>([^<]+)</font>
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30eqf)

I added/changed two things:

1. `(?![^>]*(?<!color|size|face)=)` is a negative lookahead with a nested negative look behind assertion, it does not allow an equal sign when there is not color, size or face before.
2. I changed your `[^>]*` that is matching the attributes to `(?:\s+[^>\s=]+=[^>\s=]+\s*)+`, so that it matches only non whitespace sequences that doesn't contain an equal sign.

Comment: I think that this regex also wrongly matches the 7th and the last of my examples.  So far the best solution is that by Birei. Still looking for a more compact regex solution (that doesn't contain the same attributes two times)

Comment: Have you had a look at the Regexr link? It matches all your examples the way you want.

Comment: I tested it in Regexr and I see that it also matches: <font face="verdana" color="red" size=5 size=9>randomtext</font>.   I understand that it's no sense to repeat attributes but I prefer it to exclude that match...